# Authorize requests from a user after a first request

Tags: php, authentication, uri

I need to make a script to authorize a user to browse a certain part of a site. That user has a software installed that make a url call. that's it. After that I know the user is authorized. How can I make my browser aware if the user has made or not that request? Is there a way? with cookies or http authentication?

Thank you

Comment: Are sessions what you're looking for?  Retaining info across requests for a single user?

Comment: There are several ways of doing this - it's hard to give a useful answer without know how you're authenticating users in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You know about sessions? You could e.g use a PHP Script. Writing all about sessions would be too much to explain here ... but try e.g. searching for php sessions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use sessions. Here is an example using sessions and MySQL to authenticate users: http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet1153.htm

Answer (score 0):

PHP sestion is one of the solutions (The easy one) to authorise and identify the user.
Check this tutorial: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php.

other option is HTTP authentication with PHP.
http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php